# How many concurrent messages/threads are used with a StackExchange.Redis subscription

Tags: c#, multithreading, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

Using the StackExchange.Redis client, I want to use Redis for a standard Producer/Consumer type of work load.  The documentation recommends a pattern for this:

```
sub.Subscribe(channel, delegate {
    string work = db.ListRightPop(key);
    if (work != null) Process(work);
});
//...
db.ListLeftPush(key, newWork, flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
sub.Publish(channel, "");`
```

By default each consumer would process each message sequentially.  However, using the option `multiplexer.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;` allows for messages to be processed concurrently. Thus, in high volume scenarios where many messages are published this can cause many concurrent threads to check for work and potentially process a message.

What determines *how many* concurrent threads are allowed to be processing messages at once?  In other words will the redis client invoke an unlimited number of threads to handle messages or is this throttled some how?

Is there any way to control how many concurrent messages are processing?  Or should I be trying to implement my own logic to manage the consumer processing threads (rather than just allowing the subscription event thread to perform processing directly)?